# How to count the number of elements (images) received from Giphy api?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a webpage with a search bar to display images from Giphy. If you input cat in search bar it will return images of cats. I want to be able to return a phrase saying no image has been displayed if there is no image received from Giphy.

```
function getData(input) {
    var API_KEY = "641tN8d43jDctQRXw2OAbBG0FmiqJ4I3";
    var url =
      "https://api.giphy.com/v1/stickers/search?api_key=" +
      API_KEY +
      "&q=" +
      input +
      "&limit=5&offset=0&rating=g&lang=en"; /*this return 5 stickers at a time*/
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => showData(data.data))
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }


  /*Display the output*/
  function showData(data) {
    data.forEach((element) => {
      let src = element.images.fixed_height.url;
      var output = document.querySelector(".output");
      output.innerHTML += "<img src=" + src + " >";
    });
  }

  function clearOutput() {
    var output = document.querySelector(".output");
    output.innerHTML = "";
  }
```

I did some test but something is not right in my logic, it cant count the number of elements in the array, in fact Giphy api return empty so how do i test it?

new updated: if i replace the second  i === 0
text will be displayed with images but 1 ===5 will not display the text if there is no image available.

```
   function showData(data) {
        data.forEach((element) => {
          let src = element.images.fixed_height.url;
          var output = document.querySelector(".output");
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          if (i === 0)
          {
          output.innerHTML += "<img src=" + src + " >";
          }
          
          if (i === 0) {document.getElementById("auc").innerText = "Aucune image disponible"}
        }
        });
      }
```

but i dont have any specific image name. What should i test?

Thank you in advance

Comment: you're on the right track with your showdata, but what you really need to do is get the count of elements in Data and if > 0, do the foreach, else show your custom message.

Comment: data return undefined, but src in list return 5 elements

Comment: how is that even possible?  Your loop that sets src won't even run unless you have elements.

Comment: you need to learn to debug.  Put a debugger statement right before that step and look at the value in the browser's debugger.    I can tell you though if you're looking at the value of i used in the for loop, it won't ever be undefined, because you initialized it to 0.  You need to compare to data.length.  Additionally, above, your check is inside the for loop so I definitely won't ever be undefined as that loop won't even run unless there's records in data in the first place.

Comment: problem Giphy is returning empty so i try with  if (typeof i === 'undefined') but how do you test emptyness terminal return:  console.log(i)
+             ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (i:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure if this will fix all your issues but your logic is wrong.  Make these changes:

```
function showData(data) {
if (data.length > 0) {
    data.forEach((element) => {
      let src = element.images.fixed_height.url;
      var output = document.querySelector(".output");
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         if (i === 0)
         {
            output.innerHTML += "<img src=" + src + " >";
         }
  
       }
    });
  } else {
  document.getElementById("auc").innerText = "Aucune image 
 disponible"
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it is working now. The else needed to be inside the last bracket and erase the second if.

Comment: oh yes i see that.

Comment: To make this useful for other people (and the OP) you should explain what you changed and why.

Comment: I'm working on it.  The changes i made are directly in relation to the feedback the op gave me, so i don't think he'll have an issue.

Comment: ok i'm not sure why but the edit history isn't showing my notes.  They are as thus:  Due to the fact i copied the op's code, it had two conflicting if statements instead of an if/else, and since the section didn't run at all when there was no data, I pulled that code into the bottom out of that loop.